# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process data parcel size 1245464 bytes error

Tags: java, android

I'm afraid I'm getting an error because of the image size, but I do not have much code knowledge. How do I fix the source code below?

==========================================================================

Logcat Error Message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: im.r_c.android.puz, PID: 18376

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1245464 
bytes
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4006)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1245464 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:748)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4636)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3998)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

=========================================================================

It's a puzzle game App.two Activity source code

GameActivity.java

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private static final String TAG = "GameActivity";
   public static final int SPAN_COUNT = 3;
   public static final int BLANK_BRICK = 8;
   public static final int[][] GOAL_STATUS = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, BLANK_BRICK}};
   public static final int MAIL_GAME_STARTED = 100;
   public static final int MAIL_STEP_MOVED = 101;
   public static final int MAIL_GAME_WON = 102;
   public static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE = 100;

   private Bitmap mFullBitmap;
   private Bitmap[] mBitmapBricks = new Bitmap[SPAN_COUNT * SPAN_COUNT];
   private Timer mTimer;
   private long mStartTime;
   private int mStepCount;

   private TextView mTvTime;
   private TextView mTvStep;
   private Button mBtnChooseAndStart;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        window.setEnterTransition(new Explode());
        window.setExitTransition(new Explode());
    }




    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    Mailbox.getInstance().atHome(this);

    mTvTime = findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
    mTvStep = findViewById(R.id.tv_step);
    mBtnChooseAndStart = findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_and_start);
}
}
```

ChooseActivity.java

```
public class ChooseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int CHOOSER_SPAN_COUNT = 2;

private final int[] mResIds = new int[]{
        R.mipmap.pic_1, R.mipmap.pic_2, R.mipmap.pic_3,
        R.mipmap.pic_4, R.mipmap.pic_5, R.mipmap.pic_6,
        R.mipmap.pic_7, R.mipmap.pic_8
};

private Uri[] mUris = new Uri[mResIds.length];


private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

private static int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose);

    for (int i = 0; i < mResIds.length; i++) {
        mUris[i] = ResUtils.getUriOfResource(this, mResIds[i]);
    }

    initView();
}

private void initView() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_pics);
    assert recyclerView != null;
    CommonRecyclerViewAdapter<Uri> adapter = new CommonRecyclerViewAdapter<Uri>(this, mUris, R.layout.choose_pic_item) {
        @Override
        public void onItemViewAppear(ViewHolder holder, Uri uri, int position) {
            holder.setViewImageResource(R.id.iv_image, mResIds[position]);
        }
    };
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CommonRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            returnUri(mUris[position]);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, CHOOSER_SPAN_COUNT));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SquareGridSpacingItemDecoration(this, R.dimen.brick_divider_width));
}
}
```

How can I modify the source code?

Comment: could you please post your logcat error message

Comment: I uploaded logcat error message, please Help me once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this happens when there huge amount of data getting exchanged between a service and an application,(This involves transferring lots of thumbnails). Actually data size was around 500kb, and the IPC transaction buffer size is set to 1024KB. I am not sure why it exceeded the transaction buffer.

This also can occur, when you pass lot of data through intent extras.
So what ultimately took resolve this **TransactionTooLarge** Exception, was to identify the Activity that had its subordinate fragments, views etc adding data parcels to the bundle. Then I ran this code in said Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //Clear the Activity's bundle of the subsidiary fragments' bundles.
    outState.clear();
}
```

That fixed it for me. Hope this help someone out there!